# WPF Window IsFocused

Tags: wpf, focus, window

I have a window that I .show() that seems to be having troubles telling me if it is focused or not.

Me.IsFocused is always false if there is a textbox in the window. even if you click the textbox and minimize the window the textbox.IsFocused is True.

Is there a way to determine if the window is minimized or is behind another window without using windows API functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the IsActive property for the window.

Comment: Perfect, Exactly what i was looking for !
This should be marked as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether a window is minimized you can use it's window state:

```
if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
{
    //...
}
```